# Is there a possibility that request.remote_ip can return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Are there any instances that `request.remote_ip` or `request.ip` can return `nil`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the [docs for 3.2.11](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) dont yield too much information: remote_ip "Originating IP address, usually set by the RemoteIp middleware." and nothing for ip. OP might need to go through the source to find out.

Comment: I have the same problem that request_ip is nil for every other request from the same client. ( Rails 3.2.13 on Thin 1.5.1 on Ubuntu ) Where could I start to search ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L47) it looks like the `remote_ip` is obtained from 3 separate headers, `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, and `REMOTE_ADDR`. So, if you're concerned that you might receive a request that has none of those headers, then it looks like it's possible for `remote_ip` to be nil (looks pretty much the same way in the rack implementation of `ip`). From what I've read it's pretty safe to assume the `REMOTE_ADDR` header will be present in most HTTP requests, so it's unlikely either of those values will be nil.